# Pyomo:How to define parameters related to variables

Tags: pyomo

I'm new to Pyomo.  I would like to know how to define parameters related to variables? In the following code, i want to express the parameter M.hd[i] is associated with variable M.p_dynamic[i] and other params.Because the M.hd[i] affects the following parameters. Is there any way to solve it? Thanks in advance.

```
from pyomo.environ import *
# Create a new model
M = ConcreteModel()
M.N = RangeSet(1,96)
M.p_real = Param(M.N,within=NonNegativeReals,initialize=2.0)
M.p_max = Param(M.N,within=NonNegativeReals,initialize=5.0)
M.p_dynamic = Var(M.N,within=NonNegativeReals)
d_base=[5, 8, 10, 9, 9, 5, 9, 4, 5, 4, 8, 3, 5, 2, 3, 3, 3, 1, 0, 19, 4, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1,
        3, 5, 8, 14, 26, 28, 70, 84, 130, 145, 144, 71, 77, 76, 84, 60, 100, 55, 46, 42,
        52, 50, 53, 44, 77, 55, 66, 39, 63, 67, 71, 41, 62, 62, 67, 47, 64, 62, 69, 50,
        75, 47, 43, 26, 38, 36, 42, 36, 52, 24, 24, 22, 23, 14, 16, 7, 11, 5, 7, 7, 4,
        4, 4, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0]
M.hd = Param(M.N, within=Integers)
def hd_rule(M,i):
       return M.hd[i] == floor(d_base[i-1] * (M.p_max[i] - M.p_dynamic[i]) / (M.p_max[i] - M.p_real[i] ) )
M.hd_rule = Constraint(M.N,rule=hd_rule)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can replace

```
M.hd = Param(M.N, within=Integers)
```

with

```
M.hd = Var(M.N, within=Integers)
```

This makes it possible to create the constraints using the `hd_rule`.